# ARM : boost exception - what(): boost::lock_error

Tags: robotic-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run navigation package on a development board having an arm processor. I have ubuntu 12.04 file system installed on it.

Since I am trying to test things in parts, in my current setup I have the netbook connected to turtlebot 2 and the kinect attached on it. As shipped, it has ROS Groovy installed on it. boost version. (libboost_xxx.so.1.46.1)

The navigation package is running on the ARM processor. It has ROS Fuerte on it. boost version(libboost_xxx.so.1.49.0).

Roscore is running on the netbook and I run the minimal.launch and the 3dsensor.launch file on it.

The netbook and the arm processor are connected using WIFI. Until now, I have tried gmapping and amcl. Both of them crash multiple times at different places with the same error message from the boost library.

throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >' what(): boost::lock_error

I have copied the gdb stack below.

```
Reading symbols from /root/ros/navigation/amcl/bin/amcl...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
"/root/ros/navigation/amcl/bin/amcl" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/ros/navigation/amcl/bin/amcl 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x42d04420 (LWP 3527)]
[New Thread 0x436ff420 (LWP 3528)]
[New Thread 0x43fff420 (LWP 3529)]
[New Thread 0x448ff420 (LWP 3530)]
[New Thread 0x450ff420 (LWP 3531)]
[New Thread 0x458ff420 (LWP 3532)]
[ INFO] [1370243845.085084321]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1370243845.133092869]: Received a 512 X 480 map @ 0.050 m/pix

[ INFO] [1370243845.204693663]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [1370243845.281727082]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost::lock_error

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x42d04420 (LWP 3527)]
__libc_do_syscall () at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi/libc-do-syscall.S:47
47      ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi/libc-do-syscall.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
- 0  __libc_do_syscall () at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi/libc-do-syscall.S:47

- 1  0x4096fe52 in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:67

- 2  0x40972228 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91

- 3  0x4081c770 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++.so.6

- 4  0x4081a118 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++.so.6

- 5  0x4081a118 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

On the netbook, sometimes I get the following message :

```
[ERROR] [1370229271.246944898]: a message of over a gigabyte was predicted in tcpros. that seems highly unlikely, so I'll assume protocol synchronization is lost.
```

I have the following question:

- What version of Boost library is supported by ROS.
- Could this bug occur because the netbook is running a different boost version than the development board.
- Is there a way I could debug this problem.

Thanks,
Suraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64191/arm-:-boost-exception---what():--boost::lock_error/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could get rid of this error by installing boost library version : 1.46.1

Some more details: I was following the instructions from the link below to install ROS (fuerte) on a arm processor having debian distribution.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian

At the following step :
$sudo apt-get libboost-all-dev

It installs version 1.49.0 which caused all the troubles.

Solution:
$sudo apt-get install libboost1.46-all-dev

Note: If you have already installed ROS and some packages, you cannot just uninstall 1.49.0 and install 1.46.1. Unfortunately ros binaries were linked to 1.49.0 and it complained for missing libraries.

---

Originally posted by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) with karma: 75 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eduard_d112](https://answers.ros.org/users/11991/eduard_d112/) on 2014-02-14**:
What do you suggest if I already have installed ROS? Reinstall ROS after boost 1.46? thanks.